# Syntax error in SQL statement: UPDATE for Python 3.6

Tags: python, sql, spring-boot, h2

I am attempting  to update the column **keys** of the **book** table of an H2 database (via JayDeBeApi) using this command:

```
sqlCommand = "UPDATE book SET keys = %s WHERE keys IS NULL AND id = %d"
val = (keyWords, idBook)
mydb.execute(sqlCommand, val)
```

**keyWords** is of type string and **idBook** is of type int. The table has more columns(but these are the relevant ones) and is generated using Spring-Boot:

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@Column(columnDefinition="varchar(5000)")
private String keys;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init.py", line 43, in <module>
    sql.execute(sqlCommand, val)
  File "C:\Users\Us\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 498, in execute
    self._prep = self._connection.jconn.prepareStatement(operation)
jpype._jexception.JdbcSQLExceptionPyRaisable: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE BOOK SET KEYS = %[*]S WHERE KEYS IS NULL AND ID = %D "; expected "DEFAULT, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM, WITH"; SQL statement:
UPDATE book SET keys = %s WHERE keys IS NULL AND id = %d [42001-197]
```

I see that the problem is caused by the formatting types, but I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs (actually a [bug](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/#changelog) issue to adhere to Python's [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) standard), it appears the [JayDeBe API](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi) uses qmarks, `?`, for parameter placeholders similar to most JDBC connections.

Thus, you must use these placeholders in your prepared statement for all parameter values without differentiating by types (i.e., number, string, date). The database takes care of type conversion.

```
sqlCommand = "UPDATE book SET keys = ? WHERE keys IS NULL AND id = ?"
val = (keyWords, idBook)

mydb.execute(sqlCommand, val)
```